# TileMill for Windows

Tags: tilemill, windows

After hours and days of trying to build TileMill from source on Windows, I'm more than frustrated. Is there anyone willing to share his/her up-to-date TileMill for Windows with me?

I tried to build a version a few weeks ago. But basically, I'm only interested in a version which supports setting a transparent color for raster data (which current 0.10.1 for Windows does not). It's "image-filters:colorize-alpha", that I'm interested in.